# converting scalars and lists to arrays into a function

Tags: python

I pass certain inputs to `myfun(input1, input2, input3, output)` where myfun treats these inputs as arrays. To make it more user friendly, I'm thinking of using something like `input1=np.atleast_1d(input1)`, `input2=np.atleast_1d(input2)` etc ... so that users don't have to worry if they pass a list, a scalar etc .. I'm wondering though if this a good way of doing it. In fact, after calling myfun, a user will have their inputs converted to arrays. Alternatively I could use `new_input1=np.atleast_1d(input1)` etc .. and then work with these `new_input..` in `myfun`, but it seems like a waste of memory. Suggestions?

Comment: In general, instead of having 'user friendly' functions that accept everything thrown at them, with all the complication and overhead that comes with it, are not to be preferred over clean and efficient functions that do something well - and good naming so that it's clear to whoever needs that function what it does.

Comment: At any rate, requiring a user of your function to figure out what positional parameter they need to slot their argument into is going to be bad design. What's the advantage? If you need that flexibility, either make your function more generic so that it just works for the various dimensions, or check what you're being passed at the start and act accordingly, instead of involving the user of the function in your dance.